# How to loop through an entire array separated by a char, and that char not be after the last element?

Tags: c#, foreach

Let's say we have the following since I'm working from a datatable:

`datarow.ItemArray = {items}`

I want to write out the items separated by a comma.

```
foreach(var item in datarow.ItemArray)
{
    Console.Write(item+",")
}

Console.Read()
```

When I do that, I get a comma after the item and I don't want that. I see it's because I told it to write a comma after each item but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: You could use `.Take` or a `for` loop.

Comment: try with `string.Join`

Comment: [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the separator before the item, the problem becomes "loop an array except for the first item":

```
boolean first = true;
foreach(Datarow datarow in sorted.Rows)
{
foreach(var item in datarow.ItemArray)
{
if (first)
    first = false;
else
    Console.Write(",");
Console.Write(item);
}
}
```

Comment: This works. The only problem now is that each row starts with a comma.

Comment: place `boolean first = true;` inside outer `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", datarow.ItemArray))

Console.Read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the title of your question is misleading, as you do want to iterate through all elements. You just want to avoid having the last comma. See the sample code below to achieve that:

```
datarow.ItemArray = {1,2,3,4,5}
var str = String.Join(",", datarow.ItemArray.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
Console.Write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allItemsExceptLast = datarow.ItemArray.Take(datarow.ItemArray.Length -1);
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's question. This literally takes off the last element in the array.  The OP wants all elements in the array, separated by a comma, but doesn't want a comma appearing after the last element.  But to your defense, the title of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VV7dlA) for you.  Seems like you need `String.Join`. Also, since `String.Join` takes a `params object[] values`.. you do not need the *foreach loop* to get each item in the array.

But if you don't want to use the link, here is what you need:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //object[] myArray = new object[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };

        //Console.Write(String.Join(", ", myArray));

        // Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

        // In your case...

        Console.Write(String.Join(", ", datarow.ItemArray);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
   {
     int[] datarow = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int i=0;
     do{
           Console.Write(datarow[i]+",");
           i++;
       }while(i<datarow.Length-1);
     Console.Write(datarow[i]+"\n");
  }
}
```